# How can I save the h264 encoded video as a sequence of AVPacket-s to the file using libav c++?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, encoding, save, libav

I'm trying to save video, which is generated and encoded on fly using libav (ffmpeg) functional. When I receive next non-empty AVPacket with encoded frame, I call writer.saveNextPacket() method.
Of cause, before saving, I properly init both codec and filewriter and close them in the very ending.
Here is some code:

```
#include "utils/FileWriter.h"

#define DEBUG 1

void tp::utils::FileWriter::open(const char* path, tp::encoders::IEncoder* encoder) {
    int hr;

    debI("guessing");
    format = av_guess_format(nullptr, path, nullptr);
    if (!format){
        debI("av_guess_format");
    }

    debI("allocating output");
    hr = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&formatContext, format, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (hr < 0){
        debI("avformat_alloc_output_context2", hr);
    }

    debI("allocating stream");
    stream = avformat_new_stream(formatContext, nullptr);
    if (!stream){
        debI("avformat_new_stream");
    }
    debI("setting parameters");
    AVCodecParameters* parameters = avcodec_parameters_alloc();
    hr = avcodec_parameters_from_context(parameters, encoder->getCodecContext());
    if (hr < 0){
        debI("avcodec_parameters_from_context", hr);
    }

    stream->codecpar = parameters;

    debI("opening");
    hr = avio_open(&formatContext->pb, path, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
    if (hr < 0){
        debI("avio_open", hr);
    }

    debI("writing headers");
    hr = avformat_write_header(formatContext, nullptr);
    if (hr < 0){
        debI("avformat_write_header", hr);
    }
    debI("writer is set");
}

#define DEBUG 0

void tp::utils::FileWriter::saveNextPacket(AVPacket* packet) {
    int hr;

    hr = av_interleaved_write_frame(formatContext, packet);
    if (hr < 0){
        logF("av_write_frame", hr);
    }
}

void tp::utils::FileWriter::close() {
    int hr;

    hr = av_write_trailer(formatContext);
    if (hr < 0){
        logF("av_write_trailer", hr);
    }

    hr = avio_close(formatContext->pb);
    if (hr < 0){
        logF("avio_close", hr);
    }

    avformat_free_context(formatContext);
}
```

Here is the setup part of the encoder:

```
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    if (!codec){
        logF("avcodec_find_encoder", hr);
    }
    codecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!codecContext){
        logF("avcodec_alloc_context3");
    }
    codecContext->width = parameters.width;
    codecContext->height = parameters.height;
    codecContext->bit_rate = parameters.bitRate;
    codecContext->time_base = (AVRational){1, parameters.fps};
    codecContext->gop_size = 0;
    codecContext->max_b_frames = 0;
    codecContext->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    if (parameters.preset == EncoderParameters::Preset::Fast){
        av_opt_set(codecContext->priv_data, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
    }else if (parameters.preset == EncoderParameters::Preset::Slow){
        av_opt_set(codecContext->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);
    }

    hr = avcodec_open2(codecContext, codec, nullptr);
    if (hr < 0){
        logF("avcodec_open2", hr);
    }
```

The problem: I open "output.mp4" file and assume that the class properly saves the header of the file. However, the file weights 262 bytes (there is no useful data such as frames) and it is corrupted for running video on any video players
ps: I've enabled libav logging, which seems to be ok, despite some messages:

1. [file @ 0000017a74c6c540] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
   I have some concers about the appropriateness of the whitelist as no crypto is expected
2. [AVIOContext @ 0000017a6a249100] Statistics: 266 bytes written, 2 seeks, 3 writeouts
   The actual size of the file is 262. Does it mean that there are some info leaking during saving and even the header is already broken?

I've tried to adjust various codec settings. Even turning off any speed presets. Actually, the encoder was tested in the pair with various libav decoders and image rendering and I'm pretty sure about encoder part.
Moreover, I've written the FileWriter code three times as there are some dissimilar guides. Only the current code does not throw any warnings or errors.
Give me a hint, which part of code may be wrong or provide me with some samples of using latest ffmpeg and answer my questions, please.